# Correct way to wait a condition variable that is notified by several threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I'm trying to do this with the C++11 concurrency support.

I have a sort of thread pool of worker threads that all do the same thing, where a master thread has an array of condition variables (one for each thread, they need to 'start' synchronized, ie not run ahead one cycle of their loop).

```
    for (auto &worker_cond : cond_arr) {
        worker_cond.notify_one();
    }
```

then this thread has to wait for a notification of each thread of the pool to restart its cycle again. Whats the correct way of doing this? Have a single condition variable and wait on some integer each thread that isn't the master is going to increase? something like (still in the master thread)

```
    unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(workers_mtx);
    workers_finished.wait(lock, [&workers] { return workers = cond_arr.size(); });
```

Comment: A quick queston: have you considered [`std::experimental::barrier`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/barrier)?

Answer (score 1):

I see two options here:

Option 1: `join()`

Basically instead of using a condition variable to start the calculations in your threads, you spawn a new thread for every iteration and use `join()` to wait for it to be finished. Then you spawn new threads for the next iteration and so on.

Option 2: locks

You don't want the main-thread to notify as long as one of the threads is still working. So each thread gets its own lock, which it locks before doing the calculations and unlocks afterwards. Your main-thread locks all of them before calling the `notify()` and unlocks them afterwards.

Comment: For the first one, wouldn't be easier to use. The second one doesn't work because it could happen that while the master thread is waiting for some lock other thread  that has a different lock, can cycle more than once which is something I don't want!

Comment: Not if after every cycle the worker threads release the lock, then wait for the condition variable and only if notified relock and do exactly one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing fundamentally wrong with your solution.

Guard `workers` with `workers_mtx` and done.

We could abstract this with a counting semaphore.

```
struct counting_semaphore {
  std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> m=std::make_unique<std::mutex>();
  std::ptrdiff_t count = 0;
  std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable> cv=std::make_unique<std::condition_variable>();

  counting_semaphore( std::ptrdiff_t c=0 ):count(c) {}
  counting_semaphore(counting_semaphore&&)=default;

  void take(std::size_t n = 1) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*m);
    cv->wait(lock, [&]{ if (count-std::ptrdiff_t(n) < 0) return false; count-=n; return true; } );
  }
  void give(std::size_t n = 1) {
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*m);
      count += n;
      if (count <= 0) return;
    }
    cv->notify_all();
  }
};
```

`take` takes `count` away, and blocks if there is not enough.

`give` adds to `count`, and notifies if there is a positive amount.

Now the worker threads ferry tokens between two semaphores.

```
std::vector< counting_semaphore > m_worker_start{count};
counting_semaphore m_worker_done{0}; // not count, zero
std::atomic<bool> m_shutdown = false;

// master controller:
for (each step) {
  for (auto&& starts:m_worker_start)
    starts.give();
  m_worker_done.take(count);
}

// master shutdown:
m_shutdown = true;
// wake up forever:
for (auto&& starts:m_worker_start)
  starts.give(std::size_t(-1)/2);

// worker thread:
while (true) {
  master->m_worker_start[my_id].take();
  if (master->m_shutdown) return;
  // do work
  master->m_worker_done.give();
}
```

or somesuch.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a8db79064adb9165).